# apparmor aa-logprof not asking about all dependencies

Tags: security, apparmor

In trying to write an apparmor profile for my python-flask app (which executes via gunicorn) I can't get aa-logprof to ask me about all the dependencies.

If in complain mode the application works as expected but aa-logprof doesn't come up with more suggestions (see full profile last in this post). Everywhere I read people seem to claim that aa-logprof should ask about all the dependencies, which it reads from /var/log/syslog itself. If I switch to aa-enforce the application fails and dies. Tailing syslog shows networking denied, which of course happens because I wasn't asked about it by aa-logprof. My question is not how I can enable network for the application, but rather what in my approach is incorrect since I'm not asked about all dependencies?

When in complain, network stuff is allowed (and logprof wont ask me about it?!)

```
Feb 22 20:54:40 devshed kernel: [7991608.610578] type=1400 audit(1424634880.675:68975): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="accept" profile="/usr/local/bin/gunicorn" pid=2350 comm="gunicorn" laddr=127.0.0.1 lport=5000 family="inet" sock_type="stream" protocol=6
Feb 22 20:54:40 devshed kernel: [7991608.716887] type=1400 audit(1424634880.783:68976): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="accept" profile="/usr/local/bin/gunicorn" pid=2353 comm="gunicorn" laddr=127.0.0.1 lport=5000 family="inet" sock_type="stream" protocol=6
```

When in enforced, network stuff is denied (and logprof wont ask me about it either?)

```
Feb 22 20:41:04 devshed kernel: [7990792.228716] type=1400 audit(1424634064.295:68737): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="/usr/local/bin/gunicorn" pid=2162 comm="gunicorn" family="inet" sock_type="stream" protocol=0

/usr/local/bin/gunicorn {
 #include <abstractions/base>
 #include <abstractions/bash>
 #include <abstractions/python>

 /bin/dash rix,
 /bin/uname rix,
 /etc/nsswitch.conf r,
 /etc/services r,
 /proc/*/mounts r,
 /sbin/ldconfig rix,
 /sbin/ldconfig.real rix,
 /usr/bin/python2.7 ix,
 /usr/local/bin/ r,
 /usr/local/bin/gunicorn r,
 /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml r,
 /tmp/* rw,
 /var/tmp/* a,
 /var/www/api/app.log w,
 /var/www/api/app/* r,
 /var/www/api/* a,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's your fault. 
Version 2.8.98-0ubuntu2 (present in Ubuntu 14.10) of apparmor-utils seems to be buggy. aa-genprof crashes regularly (python errors) and I noticed a similar behavior as described by you with aa-logprof. It fills up some of the rules but others seem to be left out.

Hopefully next version will be better. Newer versions are already out just not included yet.

Incidentally the crashes in aa-genprof are connected with socket rules similar with the ones you posted so I suspect the log parser has some problems.